# How do I remove these screws from my Acer Aspire AX3200-U3600A?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, case, screws

So I have this Acer Aspire AX3200-U3600A with Windows Vista (64-bit). Every night I turn it off and turn it back on in the morning. Now it's broken and I want to fix it inside...

So I got off everything except this...

[image]

And the other side (top right) is just blocked.... so help? What do I do?

Comment: Those screws look like they're holding in the PCI slot covers. You do not need to remove those to open the case.

Comment: If the PC is as the one [here](http://img.clubic.com/02409214-photo-acer-aspire-x3200-nf7a-entrailles.jpg) then all you have to do is to pull the side+top - it should be L shaped sheet - off by unsnapping.

Comment: @kobaltz AH, okay. That's why it's covered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing those two screws requires an open case to get at the screw-head. Put plainly, **you're not going to get those screws out** while the case is still on your system.

You don't want those out right now anyways, you'll need to remove those two only if you decide to install/upgrade a PCI peripheral card. Which is not applicable in your case.

You should try a different approach. There must be other screws, or a slide lever, or something else you can pry at to get in [there](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dzGRGrropM4) (skip to 2:35 of video to see the guts). I can see that the case in the video *does* slide **towards the back** and then lift away. It may be just sticking, so use more pressure? Use a slot-head screwdriver wedged to pry the case towards the back of the system.

Comment: Thanks! I got it. I pulled on the roundish trapezoid and it slide off... and now.. I got........ this. EW. Thanks, though! http://i.imgur.com/Va8Fy.jpg

Comment: Ok! I hope you have some air in a can.